# How can I include a binary framework in an Azure Pipeline?

Tags: ios, xcode, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Right now my project is using Azure Pipelines (based on a YAML file) to verify for the correct building and test passing of an Xcode project using Fastlane.
Recently we had a new requirement to add a series of binary frameworks provided by an external vendor, sadly as of now the vendor is not providing us with a distribution method for their frameworks, instead we got a zip file with the frameworks inside. All developers already have these files locally.

Given the size of the frameworks and our internal standards we are not including these frameworks into our git repository, therefore one of our building stages fails as it is unable to find the binary frameworks to build the project. Thus our pipeline is constantly failing.

I was thinking on adding a new step into the pipeline to f**etch the frameworks and add them to the directory so the build stage could find the frameworks and properly build the project** but I'm honestly clueless about where to store these vendor binaries in Azure. I've been looking into Azure Artifacts and they seem like a promising option, but I'm not sure if I could accomplish my task with it and how could I use them for such case.

I would be very glad if someone could point me on the right direction, on **how can I include these binary frameworks into my project so the pipeline could use them to build the project.**

Comment: Have you tried to use the Universal Pacakges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, you can try to create a feed in your Azure DevOps organization and publish the zip file to the feed via the Universal Packages.
And then you can use the Universal packages task to download the zip file.
[image: connect to feed]

[image: Universal packages task]
For more information, you could refer to the [publish universal packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/universal-packages?view=azure-devops).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. This was the way to achieve what I was thinking on!
Now we are currently investigating if there's a way to provide the binary framework directly from azure to all the devs, as if it was a distribution provider.
We were thinking about using Universal Packages, but sadly you can't use HTTPS to download them from terminal, just the Azure Command Line tool.